# Некорректная работа ограничения поиска адреса по Яндекс карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

На сайте подключена яндекс карта, стандартный input для ввода адреса и кнопка построения маршрута.

Всё ищется, строится и отображается, кроме одного момента.
При вводе адреса, отображается всплывающее окошко с возможными вариантами.
Я пытаюсь ограничить эти варианты нужной мне областью.
Вот пример для ленинградской области (ЛО):

```
$inputFrom.on('keyup', function(){
            //Подсказываем только если введено больше 3-ёх символов
            if ($inputFrom.val().length > 3){
                ymaps.suggest($inputFrom.val(), {
                    boundedBy:[
                        [59.349378, 29.292834],
                        [60.569502, 31.413195]
                    ]}).then(function (items) {
                        //Очищаем старые варианты
                        $sugVarWrp.empty();

                        //Добавляем новые
                        if (!items.length){
                            $sugVarWrp.hide();
                        } else {
                            items.forEach(function(item){
                            $('<p>'+item.value+'</p>').appendTo($sugVarWrp);
                        });
                        $sugVarWrp.show();
                    }
                });
            }                        
        });
```

Чувствуется, что ограничение boundedBy работает, но не идеально.
Т.е. если я его убираю, то подсказки появляются со всей России, если же добавляю, то 90% подсказок СПБ и ЛО, но бывает отобразится и из других областей или даже стран.

Я пытался получить boundedby ЛО с помощью геокодера, но безуспешно.

```
//Ленинградская область
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/',
            data: 'format=json&geocode=Красный бор, улица Калинина, 4',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
       //lowerCorner: "30.676757 59.677199", upperCorner: "30.684968 59.681351"
```

Как видно, `boundedBy` возвращается не для области, а для указанного адреса.

В итоге я просто открыл яндекс карты, прикинул область ЛО и тыкнул в нижний левый и правый верхний угол. Полученные координаы я записал в `boundedBy`.

Можно ли так?

PS
Если не найдено ни одного совпадения по адресам, то подсказка вернётся пустая или вернутся совпадения из других регионов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опция `boundedBy` в саджесте определяет приоритетную область для ранжирования поисковых подсказок, но не ограничивает жестко область поиска. Поэтому, когда вы задаете опции значение "только ЛО", выше оказываются подсказки, соответствующие заданной области, но находятся и результаты в других регионах.

Жестко ограничить область можно непосредственно при поиске, например, с использованием стандартной поисковой строки опцией `strictBounds`. [Подробнее в документации.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/?from=SO#param-parameters.options.strictBounds)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Смутило, что параметра strictBounds в документации нет в suggest, а есть только в searchControl,